# How can I extract state space (i.e., A, B, C, D) from these equations in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have two equations that have interaction together.

How can I extract state space (i.e., A, B, C, D) from these equations in Matlab?

[image]

Comment: I figured it out. The matrices of A, B, C, D are as follows :      A = [0, -(1-u)/L; (1-u)/C, -P/C];
B = [E/L; 0];
C = [0 1];

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can call them using this SS:

```
    sys = ss(A,B,C,D)
```

Have a look here:
https://au.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/ss.html#mw_83cb08e5-166f-475f-8c37-3672022583e5

Comment: But I don't have A, B, C, and D. I want to extract these matrices from that equation.